# software to auto-backup MYSQL + images etc on Server to Network HD in my house?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, backup

While i'm sure i can write a CRON to do this and some how open the ports on a network hd in my house, to be honest i'd rather spend a bit of money on some good software with a nice visual interface..

are there any such all-in-one server backup systems?

- nightly backups of the MYSQL db
- weekly backups of entire site (images etc)

my server is a VPS hosted by https://www.memset.com

Answer (score 1):

why on earth would you pay for that if you can have it for free? or maybe you just want to have a support line to call...

anyway - check [zmanda](http://www.zmanda.com/zrm-mysql-enterprise.html). if you decide to hack things on your own - i like [backupninja](https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/show/backupninja/) for orchestrating my backups.

Comment: backupninja is same link as zmanda?

Comment: @haroldo - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to backup to a network HD in your house. You probably have your reasons, but usually the upstream bandwidth at home is quite limited which would horribly slow down the restore process. Instead I would suggest backing up to some cloud storage provider that can provide decent bandwidth in- and outgoing and redundancy as well.

I use [Jungle Disk Server Edition](https://www.jungledisk.com/business/server/features/) to backup several Linux production servers. It's very affordable and has worked well. You'd set a pre-backup script to dump the MySQL db's and set Jungle Disk to backup the dumpfiles, and images. Jungle Disk de-duplicates, compresses and encrypts the data before uploading.

Jungle Disk can upload to Rackspace Cloudfiles and to Amazon S3, so your choice which storage service you prefer. There's a cross-platform application to remote control the backup services.

Answer (score 1):

For just a simple backup (daily,weekly, incremental, and so on) i just use backup-manager

http://www.backup-manager.org/

Simple, practical and it works.